# Long-term effects of a debugging session, even after detaching (linux)

Tags: c, linux, debugging, memory, gdb

Let's start by considering dynamically loaded libraries. As far as I understand, in a `smaps` output for example, you will typically see a writeable section pointing to a `.so` file that is actually marked as anonymous. For example:

```
7fa9942af000-7fa9942f1000 rw-p 03d98000 fd:0c 131627                     /usr/share/oracle/19.0.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
Size:                264 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                   4 kB
Pss:                   4 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         4 kB
Referenced:            4 kB
Anonymous:             4 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                188 kB
SwapPss:             188 kB
Locked:                0 kB
THPeligible:    0
ProtectionKey:         0
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me ac sd
```

This address range contains one anonymous page (Anonymous: 4kB), probably because of the following sequence of events:

- The range probably refers to the `.bss` section of the library, containing global variables. That's why the page is marked as writeable (permissions rw-p).
- A global variable has probably been modified, and so that the mapped page no longer matches the corresponding page in disk.
- The kernel allocates a new page under a copy-on-write strategy of the sort. The page is now anonymous because it doesn't match anymore with the corresponding file-backed page.
- If there's some page reclaim at some point in the future, that page, because it's now anonymous, could be swapped out instead of being just discarded as it happens with non-modified file-backed pages.

Ok. If I apply the same logic to a debugger creating a breakpoint, in my head the following sequence of events could happen:

- The .text section of the binary is read-only, but since the breakpoint is made with calls to `ptrace`, which is executed in kernel-mode, the kernel can modify the page because the kernel bypass permissions.
- What the debugger actually does through `ptrace` is to replace the instruction at the breakpoint location with a trap instruction, and so the corresponding page that contains the replaced instruction has been modified, and thus it becomes anonymous, as in the case above.
- When the debugger detaches and exits, if the debugger is not buggy, it will remove all the breakpoints, thus reverting all the changes done to the text.
- The kernel does not know the page has been restored to its original state (it has just witnessed a set of modifications), and so the page stay anonymous even after the debugger has exited.

That means that the debugger will cause changes on the memory layout of the process even after it exited. That means that in the case of page reclaim for example the became-anonymous pages will be swapped out instead of just being discarded as it would happen in normal circunstances. That causes a performance impact on the system since the kernel has to manage the life of more anonymous pages than before (specially if after a debugging session the user created a lot of breakpoints spreading throgh multiple pages)

If my understanding of the situation is right, do the debugger causes a performance impact even AFTER finishing the debugging session?

**NOTE:** I'm puzzle by this other case:

```
7fa994544000-7fa994545000 r--p 0002c000 103:04 10234                     /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
Size:                  4 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                   4 kB
Pss:                   4 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         4 kB
Referenced:            4 kB
Anonymous:             4 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
THPeligible:    0
ProtectionKey:         0
VmFlags: rd mr mw me dw ac sd
```

The page is read-only, file-backed, and still anonymous. How is it possible?

Comment: best to include a [mcve] so readers can try this in their personal environment. You should also pick/include a programming language, as many readers ignore linux tagged questions because of so many off-topic "I can't get kali-linux environment installed" posts . Good luck.